# Batik SVG to PDF conversion

Tags: svg, batik

I am trying to use Batik to convert am SVG to JPG. 
In the SVG I am using an external google font, and for this reason this unfortunately this fails with following error:

```
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine:
Invalid CSS document.
The "src" property does not support function values.
    at org.apache.batik.css.engine.CSSEngine.parseStyleSheet(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.css.engine.CSSEngine.parseStyleSheet(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.css.engine.CSSEngine.parseStyleSheet(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.css.engine.CSSEngine.parseStyleSheet(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.anim.dom.SVGOMStyleElement.getCSSStyleSheet(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.css.engine.CSSEngine.getStyleSheetNodes(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.css.engine.CSSEngine.getCascadedStyleMap(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.css.engine.CSSEngine.getComputedStyle(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.CSSUtilities.getComputedStyle(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.CSSUtilities.convertVisibility(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGSVGElementBridge.createGraphicsNode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.ImageTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
    at Test.main(Test.java:27)
```

Is there a way around this, or an easy way to extend Batik to support this?

This is the Java code I use:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.JPEGTranscoder;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderInput;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderOutput;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Create a JPEG transcoder
        JPEGTranscoder t = new JPEGTranscoder();

        // Set the transcoding hints.
        t.addTranscodingHint(JPEGTranscoder.KEY_QUALITY,
                   new Float(.8));

        // Create the transcoder input.
        String svgURI = new File(args[0]).toURL().toString();
        TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(svgURI);

        // Create the transcoder output.
        OutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream("out.jpg");
        TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(ostream);

        // Save the image.
        t.transcode(input, output);

        // Flush and close the stream.
        ostream.flush();
        ostream.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

And this is my SVG file:

```html
<svg data-name="Layer 1" id="Layer_1" viewBox="0 0 536.04 691.72" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <title>Test_2</title>
    <defs>
    <style type="text/css">@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine);</style>
    </defs>
    <text style="font-size: 20.289770126342773px;fill: #231f20;font-family: Myriad Pro" transform="translate(73.31 120.47) rotate(-27.42) scale(0.83 1)">Hello
        <tspan x="44.11" y="0"/>
        <tspan x="47.68" y="0">W</tspan>
        <tspan x="64.18" y="0">o</tspan>
        <tspan x="75.31" y="0">r</tspan>
        <tspan x="82.03" y="0">ld!</tspan>
        <tspan style="font-family: Marker Felt">
            <tspan style="letter-spacing: -1.2033549767559024px" x="0" y="67.55">W</tspan>
            <tspan x="16.31" y="67.55">e</tspan>
            <tspan x="26.13" y="67.55">l</tspan>
            <tspan x="31.59" y="67.55">c</tspan>
            <tspan x="41.82" y="67.55">o</tspan>
            <tspan x="52.51" y="67.55">m</tspan>
            <tspan x="69.17" y="67.55">e </tspan>
            <tspan style="font-family: Myriad Pro" x="83.37" y="67.55">t</tspan>
            <tspan style="font-family: Myriad Pro" x="89.96" y="67.55">o the </tspan>
            <tspan style="font-size: 36px;font-family: Phosphate" x="137.85" y="67.55">Jungle </tspan>
            <tspan style="font-family: Myriad Pro" x="261.4" y="67.55">!!!</tspan></tspan>
    </text>
    <text style="font-size: 12px;fill: #ec297b;font-family: Myriad Pro" transform="translate(296.88 156.85)">W
        <tspan x="9.76" y="0">el</tspan>
        <tspan x="18.6" y="0">c</tspan>
        <tspan x="23.9" y="0">ome </tspan>
        <tspan style="fill: #009345" x="49.06" y="0">t</tspan>
        <tspan style="fill: #009345" x="52.96" y="0">o </tspan>
        <tspan style="fill: #f05a28" x="62.09" y="0">the </tspan>
        <tspan style="fill: #ec1c24" x="81.28" y="0">Jungle </tspan>
        <tspan style="fill: #231f20;font-size: 60px;font-family: Marker Felt;letter-spacing: 2px" x="117.08" y="0">!!</tspan>
        <tspan style="fill: #231f20;font-size: 60px;font-family: Marker Felt" x="149.36" y="0">!</tspan></text>
    <rect height="99.22" style="fill: #ec297b" width="109.38" y="253.72"/>
    <ellipse cx="270.31" cy="269.35" rx="91.19" ry="41.55" style="fill: #e6e7e8;stroke: #231f20;stroke-linecap: round;stroke-miterlimit: 10"/>
    <rect height="136.33" style="fill: #009345;stroke: #ee4036;stroke-linecap: round;stroke-miterlimit: 10" width="136.33" x="297.07" y="355.87"/>
    <polygon points="141.5 386.05 65.64 517.45 217.37 517.45 141.5 386.05" style="fill: #e6e7e8;stroke: #231f20;stroke-linecap: round;stroke-miterlimit: 10"/>
    <ellipse cx="257.42" cy="643.57" rx="119.14" ry="47.66" style="fill: #e6e7e8;stroke: #231f20;stroke-linecap: round;stroke-miterlimit: 10"/>
    <text style="font-size: 14px;fill: #231f20; font-family: 'Tangerine', serif;" transform="translate(58.59 532.63)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</text>
</svg>
```

Thanks,
Gerald

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css"> @font-face{ font-family:"Myriad Pro"; src:url(<true type font or svg font url>}</style>
```

Batik not support woff font for rendering to image.it will take default font when you rendered with woff type.